# TWAIN example, C++

Tags: c++, twain, image-scanner

From C++ I want to set the following scanner parameters using TWAIN library: resolution, window position and histogram settings (shadow, highlight, gamma, max/min intensity). Is there any good example on the web which I could use as a starting point?

BTW, is there any reason to use commercial libraries based on TWAIN and not directly TWAIN - any advantage?

Answer (score 3):

you can download twain specification from [twain.org](http://twain.org) and start from there. [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7720/A-Copy-Utility-using-TWAIN) might help too.

for your BTW question, it's a trade-off. :) it takes time, varying from days to weeks, to learn the TWAIN specification, and it takes  money to buy a commercial library. also, commercial libraries usually come with some features beyond TWAIN as well as tech support. so, it kind of depends on budget and project schedule.

Comment: Concur with flysakura, and _weeks_ is more likely than _days_.